# Has anyone experienced copying files with Thunar from a hard-drive to a usb drive and suddenly several directories on the hard-drive have been zeroed

Tags: usb, files, thunar

I used 'disks' and the drive tested okay. Did a repair file system - nothing.
Very weird. I have lost a lot of family videos as I was collecting them together to organize.
The directory names still exist and the names of the files but they all show 0 bytes.

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** Please edit your question to include the version of the Ubuntu OS that you're running (possibly Xubuntu?), as this will help in troubleshooting your issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's too sad :(
Possible it might be due to a bad connection (cable, plug, or broken controller), so adding the drive to another computer might help.

Otherwise I could only think of recovery tools helping you, like R-Studio which maybe can access the files and copy them to another drive.

Most important thing is to not panic and not write to the hard drive.